# Azure Publisher Portal: Couldn't downgrade App Service to free plan

Tags: azure, azure-marketplace, azure-store

We have a free and a paid plan at our App Service. Users can upgrade the free plan to the paid one, but we provide the possibility to "downgrade" to the free plan.
At the Publisher Portal  the free plan can migrate from the paid one and also the paid one can migrate from the free one.

But at the Azure Management Portal if I select our App Service and click the Manage button I see a disabled radion button when I try to downgrade to the free plan.

Is it possible to downgrade from a paid plan to a free one?

Comment: is the app service a web app?

Comment: We build a Resource Provider (web service) like SendGrid for the Azure store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Azure does not support downgrade.